# C#: The type name <type_name> does not exist in the type <type>; In one class, calling a method from another class

Tags: c#, class, methods, types, typename

C#
I searched but couldn't find the specific situation I find myself in. How do I call a method in one class from another class?

```
public class Box
{
    public double length;   // Length of a box
    public double breadth;  // Breadth of a box
    public double height;   // Height of a box

    public double Volume(double len, double bre, double hei)
    {
        double totvolume;
        totvolume = len * bre * hei;
        return totvolume;
    }

}

public class Boxtester
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Box Box1 = new Box();   //create new class called Box1
        Box Box2 = new Box();   //create new class called Box2

        double returnvolume;    //create variable to hold the returned data from method


        // box 1 specification
        Box1.length = 6.0;
        Box1.breadth = 7.0;
        Box1.height = 5.0;

        // box 2 specification
        Box2.length = 11.0;
        Box2.breadth = 16.0;
        Box2.height = 12.0;


        //Calculate and display volume of Box1
        Box.Volume volumebox1 = new Box.Volume();                                 //creating new instance of Volume method called volumebox1
        returnvolume = volumebox1.Volume(Box1.length, Box1.breadth, Box1.height); //giving variables to method
        Console.WriteLine("Volume of Box1 : {0}", volumebox1);                    //write return value

        //Calculate and display volume of Box2
        Box.Volume volumebox2 = new Box.Volume();                                 //creating new instance of Volume method called volumebox2
        returnvolume = volumebox2.Volume(Box2.length, Box2.breadth, Box2.height); //giving variables to method
        Console.WriteLine("Volume of Box1 : {0}", volumebox2);                    //write return value

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

This gives the error "The type name 'Volume' does not exist in the type 'Box'

Comment: Have you tried changing `Box.Volume volumebox1 = new Box.Volume();                                 //creating new instance of Volume method called volumebox1
        returnvolume = volumebox1.Volume(Box1.length, Box1.breadth, Box1.height);`

to:

`var returnvolume = Box1.Volume(Box1.length, Box1.breadth, Box1.height);`?

Answer (score 3):

Your code should call the `Volume()` method, not creating a variable of type Volume which doesn't exist. Also, `Volume()` should use class members values, not parameters:

```
public class Box
{
    public double length;   // Length of a box
    public double breadth;  // Breadth of a box
    public double height;   // Height of a box

    public double Volume() 
    {
        double totvolume;
        totvolume = length * breadth * height;
        return totvolume;
    }

}

public class Boxtester
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Box Box1 = new Box();   //create new variable of type Box called Box1
        Box Box2 = new Box();   //create new variable of type Box called Box2

        double returnvolume;    //create variable to hold the returned data from method


        // box 1 specification
        Box1.length = 6.0;
        Box1.breadth = 7.0;
        Box1.height = 5.0;

        // box 2 specification
        Box2.length = 11.0;
        Box2.breadth = 16.0;
        Box2.height = 12.0;


        //Calculate and display volume of Box1
        returnvolume = Box1.Volume(); 
        Console.WriteLine("Volume of Box1 : {0}", volumebox1);                    //write return value

        //Calculate and display volume of Box2
        returnvolume = Box2.Volume(); 
        Console.WriteLine("Volume of Box2 : {0}", volumebox2);                    //write return value

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Box.Volume volumebox1 = new Box.Volume();` this line won't work. You need to call the method of box1 and box2 itself.

The right call would be:

```
double Box1Volume = Box1.Volume(Box2.length, Box2.breadth, Box2.height);
```

I would make the volume a property, that way you can access is like a variable but get the right values.

Personally I prefer to work with Properties, that way you can, if needed, manipulate the values before accessing if that's needed constantly, like volume.

Here's my example of for it:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        Box Box1 = new Box();   //create new class called Box1
        Box Box2 = new Box();   //create new class called Box2

        // box 1 specification
        Box1.Length = 6.0;
        Box1.Breadth = 7.0;
        Box1.Height = 5.0;

        // box 2 specification
        Box2.Length = 11.0;
        Box2.Breadth = 16.0;
        Box2.Height = 12.0;

        Console.WriteLine("Volume of Box1 : {0}", Box1.Volume);
        Console.WriteLine("Volume of Box2 : {0}", Box2.Volume);     

    }
}

public class Box
{
    public double Length {get;set;}   // Length of a box
    public double Breadth {get;set;} // Breadth of a box
    public double Height {get;set;}// Height of a box
    public double Volume { get { return Length * Breadth * Height;}}
}
```

this gives the output

```
Volume of Box1 : 210
Volume of Box2 : 2112
```

Comment: The Volume setter is completely useless, also you are making a Property with a backing field which you can't use either. You could keep it as simple as 


`public double Volume { get { return Length * Breadth * Height; } }`

Comment: @Antry yeah true too, though I thought it would look a little more understandable the way I did. I'll fix the set and add your example as comment.

Comment: You're still right though :p Oh damn, everything is a property now haha

Comment: Well, I personally use properties in like 9/10 cases. Not sure if that's not a good practice but It came quite handy in times for me.

Comment: From what I know, they really don't have that much of a difference in terms of performance impact (`Field` Vs. `Property`). Where one has to be careful is to NOT use Fields and Properties when a `Local` is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static class Box1
    {
        public static double length;   // Length of a box
        public static double breadth;  // Breadth of a box
        public static double height;   // Height of a box

        public static double Volume(double len, double bre, double hei)
        {
            double totvolume;
            totvolume = len * bre * hei;
            return totvolume;
        }

    }
   public static class Box2
    {
        public static double length;   // Length of a box
        public static double breadth;  // Breadth of a box
        public static double height;   // Height of a box

        public static double Volume(double len, double bre, double hei)
        {
            double totvolume;
            totvolume = len * bre * hei;
            return totvolume;
        }

    }
    public class Boxtester
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // box 1 specification
            Box1.length = 6.0;
            Box1.breadth = 7.0;
            Box1.height = 5.0;

            // box 2 specification
            Box2.length = 11.0;
            Box2.breadth = 16.0;
            Box2.height = 12.0;

            Console.WriteLine("Volume of Box1 : {0}", Box1.Volume(Box1.length, Box1.breadth, Box1.height));
            Console.WriteLine("Volume of Box1 : {0}", Box2.Volume(Box2.length, Box2.breadth, Box2.height));


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```